# How can I remove a single file from the output of grep by index on unix?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I have a strange file on my system. When I look for a name (let's say foo), I get this:

```
kilojoules@kilojoules:~$ ls|grep "foo"
foo
foo foo
kilojoules@kilojoules:~$
```

I am having trouble deleting the file "foo foo" without deleting :foo:. Is it possible to pipe only one output of grep to xargs? something like `ls|grep "foo"|xargs[1] rm` or `ls|grep "foo" [1]|xargs rm`

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Are you wanting to get the nth line of output from the command?? Or do you just want to know how to delete files!?

Comment: I want to get the nth line of output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the last line with `tail`:

```
ls *foo* | tail -n 1 | xargs rm
```

Or you can print just the second with `sed`:

```
ls *foo* | sed -n 2p | xargs rm
```

Or you can `grep` it out by content:

```
ls *foo* | grep 'foo.*foo' | xargs rm
```

None of these shenanigans are really necessary, and all of them amount to the [discouraged practice of parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) but answering your question hopefully teaches you something about pipelines in general.

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes or single quotes to encapsulate your arguments:

```
rm "foo foo"
rm 'foo foo'
```

You can also quote the space:

```
rm foo\ foo
```

If your file arguments starts with `-`, add an extra `--` before them to prevent `rm` from interpreting them as invalid options:

```
rm -- "--foo"
```

See [Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html). Or better yet the whole [Basic Shell Features](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Basic-Shell-Features) section.

Comment: And also `rm foo*foo` if there are weird contril characters you cannot identify and/or type.

Comment: @tripleee If you do that better make it `rm -i foo*foo` to confirm deletion, otherwise you might remove files you didnt intend

Answer (score 1):

What @konsolebox suggested is definitely simple and is something even i also do frequently but in *nix systems, you can always expect weird filenames which will be difficult, if not impossible to delete using the double/single quote method. For such cases, finding the `inode number` and then deleting it using the `find` command is preferable. `find` command has a `delete` switch for such purposes.

```
[gc@slave ~]$ ls -li
total 8
19214 -rw-rw-r-- 1 gc gc   0 Aug 10 11:35 foo
35660 -rw-rw-r-- 1 gc gc   0 Aug 10 11:35 foo foo

[gc@slave ~]$ find . -type f -inum 35660 -delete

[gc@slave ~]$ ls -ltr
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gc gc   0 Aug 10 11:35 foo
```